# Retrieving the Post Request response from api and passing it on to another post request to be passed on to angular8 app

Tags: javascript, angular, http, routes, response

I am using the [Face Recognition and Face Detection api by lambda](https://rapidapi.com/lambda/api/face-recognition-and-face-detection?endpoint=53aa3243e4b07e1f4ebe9bb3) and I need to get a response from the api using post which I need to subscribe to in my angular app. The structure is as follows: an image is passed to **angular app -> Route.js -> function.js**. It then gets processed by the api and passes a post response. Now, since this passes a post response in function.js how do I get it back up the structure **function.js->Route.js->angular app**? From Route.js-> angular I now I can set objects via the res.status(200).json(object) method but how about the response from function.js?

**function.js**

```
this.recognizeImg = (url)=>{
        let requestString = "https://lambda-face-recognition.p.rapidapi.com/recognize";
        let req = unirest("POST", requestString);
        let imgURL = url;

        unirest.post(requestString)
           .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", API_KEY)
           //.field("urls", imgURL)
           .attach("files", fs.createReadStream(createPath(imgURL)))
           .field("album", ALBUM_NAME)
           .field("albumkey", ALBUM_KEY)
           .end(result => {
               console.log("successfully recognized image");
               console.log(result.body);
           });   


    }
```

**Route.js**

```
facedetAPIRoutes.route("/").post(function (req, res){
    let imageUrl = req.body.url;
    myFaceDetAPI.recognizeImg(imageUrl);
    res.status(200).json(myFaceDetAPI.recognizeImg(imageUrl));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use promise for this asynchronous operations :

```
this.recognizeImg = (url)=>{
        let requestString = "https://lambda-face-recognition.p.rapidapi.com/recognize";
        let req = unirest("POST", requestString);
        let imgURL = url;
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
           unirest.post(requestString)
           .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", API_KEY)
           //.field("urls", imgURL)
           .attach("files", fs.createReadStream(createPath(imgURL)))
           .field("album", ALBUM_NAME)
           .field("albumkey", ALBUM_KEY)
           .end(result => {
               console.log("successfully recognized image");
               console.log(result.body);
               resolve(result.body) // giving response back
           });
        });

       return promise;
    }
```

now in Route.js:

```
facedetAPIRoutes.route("/").post(function (req, res){
let imageUrl = req.body.url;
myFaceDetAPI.recognizeImg(imageUrl).then(function(res) { 
 // here is your response back
 console.log(res)
});)
```

});

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answer your question but to get the response from the API call back to your function, you can listen to the promise returned from unirest.post i.e. add return before unirest.post line and within your function you can use then because you will get a promise